# The formation of the past participle of verbs

Tags: grammaire

I am learning "le passé composé avec être et avoir" and how to change the endings of verbs that end in "er", "ir" and "re". What about the verb "nettoyer"? What would the auxiliary verb be? For example, how would you say "my sister cleaned her room"?

Comment: [The passé Composé](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/french/french-ii/french-ii-past-tenses/the-passe-compose). [The perfect tense: a complete example](http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/perfect_tense_example.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

The auxiliary verb for the verb "nettoyer" is "avoir. You have to say "Ma sœur **a nettoyé** sa chambre.".

Here is something to start on the study of how to get the basic ending for  the past participles of verbs : https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/participe-passe-1.php.
Then you'll have to learn the irregular forms and this reference will help you : https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/les-participes-passes-irreguliers-47.php.

Comment: How did you what to change the ending to?

Comment: I see, you mean "how do you know what is the ending for the past participle?" . So what you want is rules so as to know how to find the past participle of verbs; is that it ?

Comment: Yes! Is there any rule to follow?

Comment: I join a ready made explanation to the answer. It's good enough for a start.

Comment: Thanks so much!